# Redirects not working in chrome.identity

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, google-chrome-app

I've been working on a chrome app that uses the `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` API to authenticate users against their Google account.

The setup:

1. Clicking the login button in the app executes this code:

    `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({'url': <AUTH-URL>, 'interactive': true},
           function(redirect_url) {
               <handle URL here>
           }
    });`

`<AUTH-URL>` points to an endpoint on my own server, which redirects to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://<APP-ID>.chromiumapp.org/...&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force`

This flow was working fine till two days ago. Clicking the button would open the chrome identity window, show the Google sign in page, and entering my credentials would call the callback function.

This stopped working today. I just see a 'Authorization page could not be loaded' message as soon as I click on the login button.

I tried setting a 5-second delay on the server (before the redirect), but the 'Authorization page could not be loaded' message appears before the 5 seconds are up.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: Could you please provide the value of `redirect_url`?

Comment: Hi @Osiris, any luck on finding out why this is happening ? I've got the same issue with chrome.identity.getAuthToken, it's not working anymore without any changes. Same error message..

Comment: @brian see answer. The "Authorization page could not be loaded" message is the generic message returned by the Chrome API in case of any error, so I'm not sure if the answer applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

We finally figured this out after 2 days of the login flow not working. The page that was being rendered (`<AUTH-URL>`) contained a Google Tag Manager snippet.

We'd recently updated that to include MixPanel. This was causing a few `<script>` elements with the `async` attribute to be injected into the page. Removing Mixpanel from GTM solved the problem instantly.

I'm guessing it was the removal of the `<script async ...>` that did the trick. It was not just the OAuth flow - simple `<a>` links weren't working either.